# How to export a Oracle Schema with toad

Tags: oracle, toad

I'm a beginner with Oracle database and I'm trying to export a schema with Toad.

I'm using the function "**database -> export -> generate schema script**".

I want to save the schema in another Oracle database instance, on another machine, using toad.

What it's not clear is if when  I use that function, I create only a script of the **schema**, or a script of **schema** and **user** and **tablespace** as well.

Thank you

Comment: Well one way to find out would be to run the command and *see what happens*.

Comment: Just being curious - which TOAD version is it? My 12.5 doesn't have that option (but has some others).

Comment: Mine is 12.0.0.61